# MDM Terms of Use endpoint is not correctly configured

Tags: azure, active-directory

I have three laptops and one desktop joined to Active Directory hosted on Azure. I am trying to join a new workstation to Azure AD using the email address of a person who has a laptop connected to Azure.

Here are my steps.

1. Connect to Work or School.
2. Connect.
3. Join this device to Azure Active Directory.
4. Enter user's email address and password.

I receive the following error when trying:

"Looks like the MDM Terms of Use endpoint is not correctly configured."

I've checked whether "Users may join devices to Azure AD" is set to ALL. (It is.)
The number of devices per user is set to 20.

Where do I go the portal to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

I know that this is an old question but I'm hoping it can help others avoid hours or days trying to figure out. Even Microsoft couldn't figure this one out which is sad. Their documentation actually even contradicts the solution.

During your domain setup, there are two CNAME records that you are instructed to create: EnterpriseEnrollment and EnterpriseRegistration. What they don't tell you is that **this is only used if you are using the free MDM for Office 365 solution. If you are using, or switch to a license of Active Directory Premium and/or Intune, you MUST remove these CNAME records in order to allow your devices to register.** It worked for me instantly upon removing the records on Cloudflare, though there may be a delay depending on who you use for DNS management.

I hope this helps anyone encountering this issue. Microsoft really needs to work on the detail of their error messages.

Answer (score 0):

I see you got a couple answers on Reddit - but here goes,
 Firstly, make sure you have one of the more advanced AAD services ([such as P2](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/cloud-platform/azure-active-directory-pricing)) not the free one which has almost nothing whatsoever to do with AD.

AAD seems to "propagate" slowly ala Y2K Domains. I get this error often and there might be more than 1 root cause (thanks to the cryptic message in the first place).

Similar symptoms:

1. MDM TOU error when activating brand-new PC
2. Vague error regarding connectivity when setting PIN
3. "Successfully" connecting to work but no listing in Intune

For all of the above, I find **simply waiting about 24 hours** before trying again often helps as the newly created *user/device/passport/hello* propagates through Microsofts complex cloud ID servers.

I have had it fail with your message and then **retry 30-seconds later and it works** (forever from then-on) and I have had devices which "join the workplace successfully" but not show up in Intune/AAD for **almost 48 hours**!